# Don't understand integration using a substitution rule for a square root function.

Tags: calculus, integration

As an example, evaluate $(1) \int \sqrt{2x + 1} \mathrm{d}x$.

One way would be to let $u = 2x+1$, and I do understand that one as it clearly fits with my conception of the substitution rule as a sort of "reverse chain rule" for antiderivatives - this choice of $u$ leads to $\mathrm{d}u=2\mathrm{d}x$, which then needs to be corrected by a multiplication of $\frac{1}{2}$ for the missing 2 in ***(1)***.

**However**, another possible substitution is apparently $u= \sqrt{2x+1}$, which leads to $\mathrm{d}u=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{2x+1}}$.

I don't get this at all. If the substitution rule is $$\int f(g(x))g'(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int f(u)\mathrm{d}u$$ with $u=g(x)$, then what exactly is $g'(x)$ and what is $f(x)$ supposed to be in the latter substitution approach? And what is the correction factor? I just can't wrap my head around it (I'm a beginner, so please keep that in mind!)

Comment: if you're satisfied with you're answer, then please click the green check to close the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With $f(u)=u^2$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{2x+1}$, the substitution rule gives
$$
\int u^2 \, du
= \int f(u) \, du
= \int f(g(x)) \, g'(x) \, dx
= \int (\sqrt{2x+1})^2 \, \frac{2}{2\sqrt{2x+1}} \, dx
= \int \sqrt{2x+1} \, dx
.
$$
Now read this chain of equalities from right to left, to get it in the order that you would normally write the calculation:
$$
\int \sqrt{2x+1} \, dx
= \dots
= \int u^2 \, du
= \frac{u^3}{3} + C
= \frac{(\sqrt{2x+1})^3}{3} + C
= \frac{(2x+1)^{3/2}}{3} + C
.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We have:
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= x^2 \\
g(x) &= \sqrt{2x + 1} \\
g'(x) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x + 1}}
\end{align*}
which leads to:
\begin{align*}
\int \sqrt{2x + 1} ~\mathrm{d}x
&= \int (\sqrt{2x + 1})^2 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x + 1}} ~\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int u^2 ~\mathrm{d}u
\end{align*}

---

**Remark:** Observe that if $u = \sqrt{2x + 1}$, then:
\begin{align*}
u^2 &= 2x + 1 \\
2u~\mathrm{d}u &= 2~\mathrm{d}x \\
u~\mathrm{d}u &= \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
So by replacing $\sqrt{2x + 1}$ with $u$ and by replacing $\mathrm{d}x$ with $u~\mathrm{d}u$, we obtain:
$$
\int \sqrt{2x + 1} ~\mathrm{d}x
= \int (u) (u~\mathrm{d}u)
= \int u^2 ~\mathrm{d}u
$$

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, I don't understand the part with the remark. It's the same explanation as in my book, so understanding that would really help!

Comment: What's unique about choosing $u = \sqrt{ax + b}$ is that you can express the derivative in terms of itself. That is, since $u' = \frac{a}{2u}$, we can do this:
\begin{align*}
u^2 &= ax + b \\
2u~\mathrm{d}u &= a~\mathrm{d}x \\
\frac{2}{a}u~\mathrm{d}u &= \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
The goal is to "solve for $\mathrm{d}x$" (and make other substitutions) such that the integral can be expressed purely in terms of $u$ instead of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct the initial idea behind the substitution integrals is the reverse of the chain rule. We look for a composition of two functions which is clear here it is $f=\sqrt{x}$ and $g= 2x+1$. Or we could have $g = \sqrt{2x+1}$ and $f=x^2 $
$$\int \sqrt{2x+1 } dx = \int \underbrace{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2x+1}}}_{g'} \underbrace{\left(\sqrt{2x+1}\right)^2}_{f(g)} dx $$

But when you master the idea of the integral of substitution sometimes its going to be hard to guess what is $g$ and $f$ are for example

$$\int \frac{x^5}{\sqrt{x^3+1}} dx $$ here we usually go by letting $u$ be the inside of the square i.e. the function which is inside another function. Here if you try it you will see that $du = 3x^2 dx$ then $x^2$ will cancel to have $x^3$ in top which can be written in terms of $u$. So in future what you will do is try to guess a good $u$ such that when you eliminate $x$ you will get something we can integrate easily. What am trying to say you should think about the substitution method as writing the function in way where we can integrate. I hope that helped you

Answer (score 0):

**You're on the right track!**

Let $u= \sqrt{2x+1}$. This leads to $\mathrm{d}u=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{2x+1}}$, thus $ \sqrt{2x+1}\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{d}x$. By definition of $u$, we have $ u\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{d}x$.

Now we substitute $u$ and $\mathrm{d}u$ into the integral as follows

$$ \int \sqrt{2x+1}\mathrm{d}x= \int u \mathrm{d}x = \int u (u\mathrm{d}u) = \int u^2 \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{3}u^3+C = \frac{1}{3}(\sqrt{2x+1})^3+C$$